# Javascript: Website runs fine on my computer, but on older computer it hangs the site

Tags: javascript

```
function ImageExist(url) 
            {
                var num;
               $.ajax({
                url:url,
                error: function()
                {
                   num = 0;
                },
                success: function()
                {
                    num = 1;
                }
            });
            return num;
            }

           function  ChangeColor(color, type){ 
           var count = 1;
        while(ImageExist("images/"+type+"/"+color+"/"+count+".jpg") != 0){
            count++;
        }
            var str = "";
            var cm = new Array(count);
           for(var i = 1; i < count; i++){
               cm[i] = "<img src=\"images/"+type+"/"+color+"/"+i+".jpg\" onclick=\"ChangeImg('"+type+"','"+color+"','"+i+"')\">";
               str = str+cm[i];
           }  
           document.getElementById("prodPhoto").innerHTML = cm[1];
           document.getElementById("prodPhotos").innerHTML = str;


            }

            function ChangeImg(type, color, img){
                var light = "<a href=\"images/"+type+"/"+color+"/"+img+".jpg\" rel=\"lightbox[sofa]\" title=\"Comfort M\"/>";
                document.getElementById("prodPhoto").innerHTML = light+"<img src=\"images/"+type+"/"+color+"/"+img+".jpg\">"+"</a>";
            }
            function preload(arrayOfImages) {
            $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            (new Image()).src = this;
            // Alternatively you could use:
            // (new Image()).src = this;
            });
            }
```

This code is supposed to find out how many images is there for each folder called product and color. Then output them to html page. It works fine on my laptop but on college network it hangs the site.

Could this be related to not being administrator?

Comment: I'd try dropping some `console.log()`s in there and seeing where exactly it's hanging. It could be a number of reasons, first that comes to my mind is a difference in browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact you have a while loop with asynchronous Ajax calls in a synchronous while loop, that is asking for the browser to lock up. There is no reason to make an Ajax call to see if an image exists. Use an image tag in an asynchronous manner.

The code is not 100% meet your needs, just a basic example.

```
function checkImage( url, good, bad) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = good;
    img.onerror = bad;
    img.src = url;
}

function findImgs () {
   var currentImg = -1;
   function next(){
       currentImg++
       checkImage("foo" + currentImg + "jpg", next, done);
   }
   function done() {
       currentImg--;
       alert("last Good Count was " + currentImg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're executing a massive amount of ajax calls inside your `while` statement because your `imageExist` function is asynchronous but when you return your `num` variable is always `undefined`. So your code says, *«while the function return something different than 0 increment count and try again.»*

Take a look at your javascript console on firefox, under `net` panel